# Filtering on grouped variable maintaining sequence

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe :

```
df <- data.frame(
        Group=c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'),
        Activity = c('EOSP','NOR','EOSP','COSP','NOR','EOSP','WL','NOR'),
        TimeLine=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
      )
```

I want to filter for **only** two activities for each group and in the order in which I am filtering. For example, I am only looking for the activities `EOSP` and `NOR` but in the order too. This code:

```
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
        filter(all(c('EOSP','NOR') %in% Activity) & Activity %in% c('EOSP','NOR'))
```

results in:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group Activity TimeLine
  <fct> <fct>       <dbl>
1 A     EOSP            1
2 A     NOR             2
3 A     EOSP            3
4 B     NOR             1
5 B     EOSP            2
6 B     NOR             4
```

I don't want row 3 as `EOSP` occurs after `NOR`. Similarly for group B, I don't want row 4, as `NOR` is occurring before `EOSP`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: what if there are multiple `'EOSP'` and `'NOR'` in the required order. Do you want to keep them as well?

Comment: @RonakShah, yes, as there could be multiple such activities for each group. Basically there are timestamps associated with these activities and I am trying to calculate the time difference between them. Thanks for helping me twice today!

Comment: Why not just add `... %>% distinct(Activity)` in your code? i.e. `df %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(all(c('EOSP', 'NOR') %in% Activity) & Activity %in% c('EOSP', 'NOR')) %>% distinct(Activity)`

Comment: @Sotos, not quite. This still does not maintain the **order** in which I need the data. With your code, for group B, I get the values `NOR` and `EOSP` corresponding to TimeLine 1 and 2 for group B. However I need `EOSP` and `NOR` corresponding to TimeLine activities 2 and 4. Additionally, there could be multiple such pairs of activities within the same group.

Comment: Oh so you always want the first `EOSP` and the following `NOR` ?

Comment: That's correct. The order is important.

Comment: @Dhiraj Perhaps you should remove the "_also in the order specified in the TimeLine_", because your order is _not_ determined by TimeLine within group B.

Comment: @Henrik good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `match` to get the first instance of `Activity == EOSP` and use `slice` to remove everything before that. Once you do that, then you can remove duplicates and filter on `EOSP` and `NOR`, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(Group) %>% 
 mutate(new = match('EOSP', Activity)) %>% 
 slice(new:n()) %>% 
 distinct(Activity, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
 filter(Activity %in% c('EOSP', 'NOR'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
> # Groups:   Group [2]
>   Group Activity TimeLine   new
>   <fct> <fct>       <dbl> <int>
> 1 A     EOSP            1     1
> 2 A     NOR             2     1
> 3 B     EOSP            2     2
> 4 B     NOR             4     2
> ```

**NOTE 1:** You can `ungroup()` and `select(-new)`

**NOTE 2:** The warning messages being issued here

> (Warning messages:
>   1: In new:4L : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
>   2: In new:4L : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used
>   )

do not affect us since we only need it to use the first element since all are the same anyway

Comment: that's brilliant! Made a small change as in my original data, sometimes the activity `EOSP` doesn't exist in a particular group, leading to NAs. So just before your `slice(new:n())`, added a `na.omit() %>%`

Answer (score 3):

here is an option with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package: you join `df` with itself, subsetted it to keep only `EOSP` `Activity` and computing the min of `TimeLine` by group, then you can keep only the rows with `TimeLine` greater or equal to this `TimeLine`, in order to be sure you keep `NOR` only if there is `EOSP` before. Then you drop duplicated Group and Activity if you want to only keep 2 activities per group:

```
df[df[Activity=="EOSP", min(TimeLine), by=Group], on="Group"][Activity %in% c("NOR", "EOSP") & TimeLine >= V1][!duplicated(paste(Group, Activity))]

#   Group Activity TimeLine V1
#1:     A     EOSP        1  1
#2:     A      NOR        2  1
#3:     B     EOSP        2  2
#4:     B      NOR        4  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` idea:

```
df %>%
  filter(Activity %in% c('EOSP','NOR')) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(tmp = which(Activity == 'EOSP' & !duplicated(Activity))) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in%  c(tmp, tmp+1)) 

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group Activity TimeLine   tmp
  <fct> <fct>       <dbl> <int>
1 A     EOSP            1     1
2 A     NOR             2     1
3 B     EOSP            2     2
4 B     NOR             4     2
```